# Library ghc RULES don't activate

Tags: haskell, ghc

`fgl` is a Haskell library for graph manipulation. This library comes with an implementation of its base classes - `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` - that is supposedly highly tuned for performance. Part of that performance tuning involves ghc RULES pragmas to replace certain generic functions with specialized versions that are much faster.

However, my evidence is that these RULES don't seem to work at all, and I don't understand why not. For people trying to replicate exactly what I see, I've put my test project up at https://github.com/fizbin/GraphOptiTest and am using ghc version `7.10.2`.

---

Here's my test program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

module Main where

import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Data.Graph.Inductive
import qualified Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree as Pt
import qualified MyPatriciaTree as MPt

makeGraph :: (DynGraph gr) => Int -> gr () Int
makeGraph n = mkGraph (map (,()) [1 .. n])
  (concatMap (\x -> map (\y -> (x, y, x*y)) [x .. n]) [1 .. n])

main1 :: IO ()
main1 =
  replicateM_ 200 $ let x = makeGraph 200 :: Pt.Gr () Int
                    in evaluate (length $ show x)

main2 :: IO ()
main2 =
  replicateM_ 200 $ let x = makeGraph 200 :: MPt.Gr () Int
                    in evaluate (length $ show x)

main :: IO ()
main = main1 >> main2
```

Now, `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` has this definition for the class function `mkGraph`:

```
    mkGraph vs es   = insEdges es
                      . Gr
                      . IM.fromList
                      . map (second (\l -> (IM.empty,l,IM.empty)))
                      $ vs
```

Where `insEdges` is a function defined in the module `Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph` as:

```
insEdges :: (DynGraph gr) => [LEdge b] -> gr a b -> gr a b
insEdges es g = foldl' (flip insEdge) g es
```

And `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` has this to say about `insEdge`:

```
{-# RULES
      "insEdge/Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree"  insEdge = fastInsEdge
  #-}
fastInsEdge :: LEdge b -> Gr a b -> Gr a b
fastInsEdge (v, w, l) (Gr g) = g2 `seq` Gr g2
  where
    g1 = IM.adjust addSucc' v g
    g2 = IM.adjust addPred' w g1

    addSucc' (ps, l', ss) = (ps, l', IM.insertWith addLists w [l] ss)
    addPred' (ps, l', ss) = (IM.insertWith addLists v [l] ps, l', ss)
```

So, in theory, when I run `main1` in my test program I should get that compiled down into something that eventually calls `fastInsEdge`.

To test this, I compare against a modified version of `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` that uses this as its definition of the `mkGraph` method: (this is the class `MyPatriciaTree` used above in `main2`)

```
    mkGraph vs es   = doInsEdges
                      . Gr
                      . IM.fromList
                      . map (second (\l -> (IM.empty,l,IM.empty)))
                      $ vs
      where
        doInsEdges g = foldl' (flip fastInsEdge) g es
```

When I run my test program (after `cabal configure --enable-library-profiling --enable-executable-profiling` and `cabal build GraphOptiTest`), though, the `main2` method smokes the `main1` method. It isn't even close - the profile shows 99.2% of the program's time is spent inside `main1`. (and changing the program to just run `main2` shows that yes, `main2` is really fast on its own)

Yes, I do have `-O` in the `ghc-options` section of my cabal file.

Trying ghc options like `-ddump-rule-firings` doesn't really help - all I can see is that these replacement rules aren't firing, but I have no idea why. I don't know how to get the compiler to tell me why it didn't activate the replacement rules.

---

Bringing up something discovered by messing around with `fgl`'s source in response @dfeuer's answer below:

If I add a specialized version of `insEdges` to `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` as:

```
{-# RULES
      "insEdges/Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree"  insEdges = fastInsEdges
  #-}
fastInsEdges :: [LEdge b] -> Gr a b -> Gr a b
fastInsEdges es g = foldl' (flip fastInsEdge) g es
```

Then both `main1` and `main2` are now fast. This replacement rule fires; why doesn't the other one? (And no, telling ghc to `NOINLINE` the function `insEdge` does no good)

---

EPILOGUE:

So there's now a bug filed with the `fgl` package for not tagging their functions that use `insEdge` and `insNode` appropriately so that the fast versions will be used. But in my code now I work around this and the workaround may be useful in more situations, so I thought I'd share it. At the top of my code now, I have:

```
import qualified Data.Graph.Inductive as G
import qualified Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree as Pt

-- Work around design and implementation performance issues
-- in the Data.Graph.Inductive package.
-- Specifically, the tuned versions of insNode, insEdge, gmap, nmap, and emap
-- for PatriciaTree graphs are exposed only through RULES pragmas, meaning
-- that you only get them when the compiler can specialize the function
-- to that specific instance of G.DynGraph. Therefore, I create my own
-- type class with the functions that have specialized versions and use that
-- type class here; the compiler then can do the specialized RULES
-- replacement on the Pt.Gr instance of my class.
class (G.DynGraph gr) => MyDynGraph gr where
  mkGraph :: [G.LNode a] -> [G.LEdge b] -> gr a b
  insNodes :: [G.LNode a] -> gr a b -> gr a b
  insEdges :: [G.LEdge b] -> gr a b -> gr a b
  insNode :: G.LNode a -> gr a b -> gr a b
  insEdge :: G.LEdge b -> gr a b -> gr a b
  gmap :: (G.Context a b -> G.Context c d) -> gr a b -> gr c d
  nmap :: (a -> c) -> gr a b -> gr c b
  emap :: (b -> c) -> gr a b -> gr a c

instance MyDynGraph Pt.Gr where
  mkGraph nodes edges = insEdges edges $ G.mkGraph nodes []
  insNodes vs g = foldl' (flip G.insNode) g vs
  insEdges es g = foldl' (flip G.insEdge) g es
  insNode = G.insNode
  insEdge = G.insEdge
  gmap = G.gmap
  nmap = G.nmap
  emap = G.emap
```

(Had I used the `nemap` function in my code I would have included that in the class too) Then, any code of mine which was formerly written in terms of `(G.DynGraph gr) => ...` is now written in terms of `(MyDynGraph gr) => ...`. The compiler RULES activate for the `Pt.Gr` instance, and I then get the optimized version for each function.

Essentially, this trades away the ability of the compiler to inline any of these functions into the calling code and possibly do other optimizations for always getting the optimized versions. (and the cost of an extra pointer indirection at runtime, but that's trivial in comparison) Since profiling showed that those other optimizations never yielded anything significant anyway, this was a clear net win in my case.

Many people's code could use `SPECIALIZE` rules aggressively to get the optimized versions everywhere; however, sometimes that isn't possible and it wasn't in the real production code that caused my question without refactoring huge chunks of the application. I had a data structure with a member that has the type `(forall gr. G.DynGraph gr => tokType -> gr () (MyEdge c))` - that now uses `MyDynGraph` for the class constraint, but completely unwinding it to not have `forall gr.` in the signature would have been a huge effort, and such a signature prevents specialization from working across that boundary.

Comment: Nice work-around. I suspect the library itself probably *should* be using a similar technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done any experiments, but here's my guess. The `insEdge` function is not marked with a (phased) `INLINE` or `NOINLINE`, so the inliner is free to inline it whenever it's fully applied. In the definition of `insEdges`, we see

```
foldl' (flip insEdge) g es
```

Inlining `foldl'` gives

```
foldr f' id es g
  where f' x k z = k $! flip insEdge z x
```

`flip` is now fully applied, so we can inline it:

```
foldr f' id es g
  where f' x k z = k $! insEdge x z
```

Now `insEdge` is fully applied, so GHC may choose to inline it right then and there, before the rule ever has a chance to fire.

Try adding `{-# NOINLINE [0] insEdge #-}` right by the definition of `insEdge` and see what happens. If it works, submit a pull request to `fgl`.

P.S. In my opinion, this sort of thing should really be done by using class methods with defaults, rather than rewrite rules. Rules are always a bit fussy.

---

As the comments revealed, the big problem wasn't premature inlining, but rather a failure to specialize `insEdge`. In particular, `Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph` does not export an unfolding for `insEdges`, so it's impossible to specialize it, and the `insEdge` it calls, to the appropriate type. The ultimate fix was to mark `insEdges` `INLINABLE`, but I would still advise marking `insEdge` `NOINLINE [0]` out of an abundance of caution.

Comment: Nope; `{-# NOINLINE [0] insEdge #-}` didn't work. Trying again without the phase restriction, though is there any way to get the compiler to dump intermediate places where it could have applied rules, but just didn't?

Comment: And trying it again without the phase restriction as `{-# NOINLINE insEdge #-}` also failed to work.

Comment: @DanielMartin, what happens if you `SPECIALIZE` `makeGraph` to `Pt.Gr` or mark it `INLINE`? (especially with the phased `NOINLINE`, but also without, to compare). If it's using it compiled unspecialized, then the rules surely won't fire.

Comment: Well, `-ddump-rule-firings` implies that it's already getting specialized automatically. More to the point though, if I modify `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` to have a special version of `insEdges` (defined exactly as the generic version but using `fastInsEdge`), then both `main1` and `main2` are fast, so the issue isn't `makeGraph` getting inlined or not specialized; it's something about the `insEdge` rule not firing in the expansion of `insEdges`.

Comment: @DanielMartin, my point there is that the specialization has to reach (a not-yet-inlined) `insEdge` to give that rule a chance to fire. If any link in the chain decides not to specialize/inline, then it won't. Like I said, fussy. You may want to mark `insEdges` `INLINABLE` and see if that works.

Comment: Okay, so adding `{-# INLINABLE insEdges #-}` made everything fast (didn't even need a `NOINLINE` on `insEdge`). But... why? This was debugging by random code changes! Also, the description of the pragma says "In other words the choice is left to GHC, which uses the same rules as for pragma-free functions." Why then does it have any effect at all?

Comment: @DanielMartin, without `INLINABLE`, GHC may choose not to export an unfolding for `insEdges` from its module, and apparently it decides that (this should be filed as a bug against the library for sure). With `INLINABLE`, the unfolding is exported, so GHC at least has the option of inlining *or specializing* in the importing module, based on whether it sees a potential advantage there that may not have been apparent in the defining module. Yes, this is all rather flaky! I'd still advise adding the phased `NOINLINE` for `insEdge`, just to be sure.

Comment: @DanielMartin, I just [opened an issue](https://github.com/haskell/fgl/issues/26).

Comment: Actually, it appears from what --show-iface has to say that at least part of the issue is that without INLINABLE, `insEdges` is getting compiled so as to call a function `$winsEdge` instead of `insEdge`. That function is exactly like `insEdge` except that it has the signature `(DynGraph gr) => Node -> Node -> b -> gr a b -> gr a b`. That is, `$winsEdge` has the initial tuple decomposed. the INLINABLE version of `insEdges` calls the proper `insEdge`, which can get replaced by the RULE. Why? No clue.

Comment: @DanielMartin, the non-inlinable one is compiled un-specialized, using `$winsEdge`, the un-specialized compiled form of `insEdge`. The inlinable one exposes an unfolding with (approximately) the original text of the function, which uses `insEdge`. That then gets specialized properly.